How to change the Segoe MDL2 icon of a button in code behind?
I have a UWP application that contains a button with a Segoe MDL2 icon. I need to change the button icon when it is pressed. Below is the code I am trying to use.
XAML
    <Button x:Name="btnPlayPause" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE768;" Width="50" Height="50" FontSize="26" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Background="Gray" Tapped="btnPlayPause_Tapped"/>

C#
    private async void btnPlayPause_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   btnPlayPause.Content = "&#xE769";
} 


&#xE768; is the way to specify a Unicode character in XML. But in C#, you use \uE768.

As Raymond Chen said in his comment, &#xE768; is the way to specify a Unicode character in XAML. But in C#, we use \uE768.
